# Cast member of generic type to TObject?

Tags: delphi, generics, casting, delphi-2010

I am currently thinking about a scenario where I want a generic class that calls `Free` on its items **IF** these are of an object type. So I tried the following:

```
if (PTypeInfo (TypeInfo (T)).Kind = tkClass) then
  begin
  RttiType := RttiContext.GetType (TypeInfo (T));
  FreeMethod := RttiType.GetMethod ('Free');
  if (FreeMethod <> nil) then
    FreeMethod.Invoke (FInstance, []);
  end;
```

Unfortunately the last line does not compile, which is not surprising since the types do not match. The question is: can I get it to compile? I tried casting to `Pointer` and then to `TObject` but that gives me an invalid typecast error. Is there any way to get `FInstance : T` into a `TObject` reference that I can then pass to `Invoke`?

Or is there any other way to achieve what I want? Please note that the whole point is to get everything in this class, so I do not want to create a `TObjectMyClass` that just takes objects.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this sufficient?

```
if PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T))^.Kind = tkClass then
  TObject(FInstance).Free;
```

Comment: It is! I just wanted to move the RTTI part to the constructor, but I guess requesting the type info is not really expensive anyway. But you are right the whole `RttiMethod` thing is probably not necessary. Thanks and +1

Answer (score 2):

Direct cast to TObject seems to work in Delphi 2010:

```
FreeMethod.Invoke (TObject(FInstance), []);
```

Full example:

```
implementation

uses TypInfo, Rtti;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TTest<T> = class
    FInstance : T;
    procedure F;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  O : TTest<TObject>;
begin
  O := TTest<TObject>.Create;
  O.FInstance := TStringList.Create;
  O.F;
  O.Free;
end;

{ TTest<T> }

procedure TTest<T>.F;
var
  RttiType : TRttiType;
  FreeMethod : TRttiMethod;
  RttiContext : TRttiContext;
begin
  if (PTypeInfo (TypeInfo (T)).Kind = tkClass) then
  begin
    RttiType := RttiContext.GetType (TypeInfo (T));
    FreeMethod := RttiType.GetMethod ('Free');
    if (FreeMethod <> nil) then
      FreeMethod.Invoke (TObject(FInstance), []);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: :D thanks for that! lol...I should have tried that obvious solution first. I assumed it would fail so I tried to convert to `Pointer` first...which does not work...sorry for that :-/

Answer (score 2):

This smacks of poor design to me.  One of the points of generics is to get away from dynamic type decisions like this.

If you really are using the generics feature then it would make more sense to me to have a subclass with a type parameter that is constrained take only `TObject` descendents.  Since you have to decide statically how you are going to instantiate the generic class, it is no trouble whatsoever to use a `TMyObjectClass` when `T` is a class and to use `TMyClass` elsewhere.

I guess you'd be forced to take the approach you are taking if a single container needs to contain both objects and non-objects. But if that's not the case then something just feels off to me.

Comment: Delphi 2010 doesn't like restricting the type to just `TObject`. This doesn't compile: `type TSomethingGeneric<T: TObject>`, while this does: `type TSomethingGeneric<T: TStringList>`!

Comment: @Cosmin You write it so: `TSomethingGeneric<T: class>`

Comment: as I stated in the question: I do not want a subclass that handles only objects. That is the only point where a special case is necessary. Everything else is independent of the type.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just found the answer myself. `TValue.From` does the trick:

```
if (PTypeInfo (TypeInfo (T)).Kind = tkClass) then
  begin
  RttiType := RttiContext.GetType (TypeInfo (T));
  FreeMethod := RttiType.GetMethod ('Free');
  if (FreeMethod <> nil) then
    FreeMethod.Invoke (TValue.From <T> (FInstance), []);
  end;
```